# Пересылаемое сообщение в Outlook

Tags: c#, office, outlook

Когда поступает новое сообщение то он выдаёт `MessageBox` и при нажатии в нём ОК открывается только что полученное сообщение, для пересылки. Проблема в том что текст пересылаемого сообщения должен быть определённого формата а точнее Arial 10.

Код ниже

```
 private void InboxFolderItemAdded(object item)
        {
            if (item is Outlook.MailItem)
            {
                var m = MessageBox.Show("Новое сообщение в Help Desk переслать?", "HelpDesk", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly);
                        if (m == DialogResult.Yes)
                        {
                            var fEmail = ((Outlook._MailItem)item).Forward();
                            fEmail.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
                            fEmail.To = "1; 2; 3;";
                            fEmail.CC = "4;";
                            fEmail.BCC = "5; 6; 7;";
                            fEmail.Display(true);
                            fEmail.AutoForwarded = true;
                            fEmail.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceLow;
                        }


                    }
                }
```

Прошу помощи в решении данной проблемы

Comment: если формат html, то может так? `fEmail.HTMLBody = " '<style>body {font-family: Arial; font-size:10px;}</style>' " + fEmail.HTMLBody;`

Comment: @Ruslan_K сейчас попробую.

Comment: @Ruslan_K не помогло текст который был в письме остался прежним